# Grouping by first value and ordering descendingly in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Could you please confirm the correct query to show a table of accounts by name of the account and the first value of followers of each account, ordered descendingly by the number of followers?

The MongoDB collection is called "tweets".

Each document in the collection represents a tweet.

Please find one of the documents (tweets) in JSON format [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hGy4I69R6jrr3G59w1_kQyaMx1kkVF0Jb_8bXuE8ttA/edit):

I tried the following query:

```
    db.tweets.aggregate(
       [
           {
        $sort: {
          name: -1
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: {
          followers_count: 1
        }
      },

         {
           $group:
             {
               _id: "$user.name",
               followers: { $first: "$user.followers_count" }
               }
         }
       ]
    )
```

However, it's not ordering the accounts descendingly based on the number of followers of each account:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Salud_Ec",
    "followers" : 423528
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "EUPHA",
    "followers" : 4981
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "MSF International",
    "followers" : 145265
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "Ministerio de Sanidad",
    "followers" : 501492
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "NHS",
    "followers" : 479038
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : "World Health Organization (WHO)",
    "followers" : 7668030
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : "HHS.gov",
    "followers" : 945901
}
```

The desired output is to have the WHO account on the top and the EUPHA account at the bottom.

Thank you.

Comment: please add the required output?

Comment: Sure. The desired output is to have the WHO account on the top and the EUPHA account at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above query is almost correct just adjust sort stage after grouping!

```
 db.tweets.aggregate(
       [
           {
        $sort: {
          name: -1
        }
      },
      {
           $group:
             {
               _id: "$user.name",
               followers: { $first: "$user.followers_count" }
               }
         }, 
      {
        $sort: {
          followers: -1
        }
      },


       ]
    )
```